# tf.hessians() - ValueError: None values not supported

Tags: tensorflow, mathematical-optimization, derivative

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 39, in <module>
    hess = tf.hessians(loss, wrt_variables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 970, in hessians
    _gradients = array_ops.unstack(_gradients)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 952, in unstack
    value = ops.convert_to_tensor(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 639, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 704, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 113, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 360, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Variables:

```
import tensorflow as tf

data_x = [0., 1., 2.]
data_y = [-1., 1., 3.]
batch_size = len(data_x)

x = tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size], dtype=tf.float32, name="x")
y = tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size], dtype=tf.float32, name="y")

W = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=[1]), dtype=tf.float32, name="W")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1]), dtype=tf.float32, name="b")

pred = x * W + b
loss = tf.reduce_mean(0.5 * (y - pred)**2)
```

Then, following up with this code would work:

```
wrt_variables = [W, b]
hess = tf.hessians(loss, wrt_variables)
```

But this fails:

```
wrt_variables = tf.concat([W, b], axis=0)
hess = tf.hessians(loss, wrt_variables)
```

And this would also fail:

```
wrt_variables = [tf.concat([W, b], axis=0)]
hess = tf.hessians(loss, wrt_variables)
```

It also fails for reshape operations.

The complete version of this code and with comments can be seen here: 
https://gist.github.com/guillaume-chevalier/6b01c4e43a123abf8db69fa97532993f

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your graph, the node `loss` does not depend on the node `tf.concat([W,b], axis=0)`. There is no backpropagation of one onto the other, and therefore no derivative.

Tensorflow is not a formal calculus engine, it can only estimate derivatives of a node by another node if the former is downstream of the later. So for example even

```
tf.hessian(loss, 2*W)
```

will fail for the same reasons (`2*W` is a new node and `loss` does not depend on it) even though the relationship to `tf.hessian(loss, W)` is straightfoward.

Note that the sitatuation is the same with `tf.gradients`, even though it fails differently: it returns `None`s rather than throwing an exception.